# Позиционирование дочернего элемента, не закрывая контент родителя

Tags: css

Есть блок, в котором нужно сделать "стрелку" наверх, чтобы было понятно, что это за блок вообще. Проблема в том, что он перекрывает контент родителя, т.е. он идет выше по `z-index`, чем родитель. Устанавливая `z-index`, не происходит ничего. Как это пофиксить?

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Some text here, guys
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/qPYxpQ

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что вы устанавливаете `z-index` родительскому объекту. И он действительно "выше". Но вот текст внутри не выше вашей "стрелки".

Выход - обернуть текст в блок, и этому блоку поставить правильный `z-index`.

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZJzzJ)

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.block:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #aaa;
}

.block .text-block {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background: red; // хак
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text-block">Some text here, guys</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Но одна проблема - он уже не перекрывает контент, но бэкграунд остается над бэкграундом родителя. Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @Alexxosipov обновил ответ. Это требование надо было тоже указать в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы блок был под текстом, `z-index` надо ставить отрицательный (при одинаковом цвете фона проблемы с ромбом вместо треугольника не будет):

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Some text here, guys
</div>
```

Comment: А отрицательный `z-index` это нормально? Это фича или хак?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, это нормально. Стоит почитать про контекст z-index'а и как именно он работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Я так сначала сделал,а  потом засомневался))